# How to enable write access to %CACHELIB database?

Tags: intersystems-cache

Some Caché applications like [Caché Web Terminal](http://intersystems-ru.github.io/webterminal/#downloads) require write access to %CACHELIB to be enabled during installation. Is it safe? How to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling write access to %CACHELIB database is usually safe when you know what you are doing, but is **highly not recommended** if not. WebTerminal requires system-level access to work well, so enabling write access should be a temporary action.

To enable %CACHELIB write access, go to the `Management Portal`, then choose `System Administration` => `Configuration` => `System Configuration` => `Local Databases`. Then pick up `CACHELIB` database and uncheck `Always Mount Read-Only` option. Finally, press `Save` button at the top.

Do not forget to check it back after installing Web Terminal!

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can do this in terminal as:

```
%SYS>d ^DATABASE


 1) Create a database
 2) Edit a database
 3) List databases
 4) Delete a database
 5) Mount a database
 6) Dismount a database
 7) Compact globals in a database
 8) Show free space for a database
 9) Show details for a database
10) Recreate a database
11) Manage database encryption
12) Return unused space for a database
13) Compact freespace in a database
14) Defragment globals in a database

Option? 2
Database directory? /2015/mgr/cachelib/

 1)* Directory:                      /2015/mgr/cachelib/
 2)* Block size (bytes):             8192
 3)* Mirror DB Name:
 4)* Mirror Set Name:
 5)  Current Size (MB):              450
 6)  Max size (MB), 0=Unlimited:     0
 7)  Expansion size (MB), 0=Default: 0
 8)  Resource name:                  %DB_CACHELIB
 9)  Preserve global attributes:     No
10)  Global journal state:           No
11)  New global collation:           Cache standard
12)  New global growth block:        50
13)  New global pointer block:       16
14)  Read Only:                      Yes
15)* Encrypted:                      No

Field number to change? 14
Read Only? Yes => no
Field number to change?
Confirm update of database /2015/mgr/cachelib/? Yes => yes
```